.NET 9 is not visible when creating Azure Function in Visual Studio
I'm trying to create an Azure Function in Visual Studio 2022, but I don't see .NET 9 on the version list:

I just updated VS 2022:

.NET 9.0 Runtime is installed as can be seen in Visual Studio Installer

And dotnet --list-sdks also shows 9.0 is installed:

